# What is the form of the skin effect in exponentially decreasing (or exponentially increasing) voltages?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, classical-electrodynamics

I tried to replicate the standard derivation of the skin effect for exponentially shrinking or growing voltages (idealize the surface of the wire as a half-infinite volume of conductor) but I'm not sure how exactly to interpret the result. For starters in the normal derivation the solution that grows exponentially with depth is thrown out on the basis of current normalization, but if there really were an 'anti-skin effect' where the current concentrates at the center of the wire then this would be the physical solution and the normalization issue would be an artifact of the idealization (in other words we throw out one of the solutions because we know it's wrong but in this case I don't know which one ought to be wrong). Furthermore one of the two cases (I can't remember which) gives purely oscillatory behavior with depth which seems rather odd.

As for the derivation essentially all I did was follow along [this](http://alignment.hep.brandeis.edu/Lab/Derivations/Skin_Effect.html) derivation and replaced the sinusoidal behavior (as a function of $\omega t - k x$) with exponential behavior, getting either pure exponential or pure sinusoidal behavior as a function of depth (as opposed to the mixture of sinusoidal and exponential behavior you get in the AC case). I know this derivation uses assumptions that may no longer make sense in this case but I wanted to arrive at the answer quickly.

Comment: Intuitively it sounds like a non-trivial boundary condition problem to me. The Fourier component for $\omega=0$ for an exponentially increasing current or voltage would be infinite and how that components gets "distributed" around the conductor may depend on the boundary condition, especially on where we place the voltage source (at the edge of the conductor or in the bulk?). That's as far as I can guestimate my way around the problem, but I am curious what the mathematically more inclined have to say about it.

Comment: It might be interesting to see your derivation - can you edit it into your question? Some non trivial math needed...

Comment: @CuriousOne What about a physically realistic scenario like discharging a capacitor starting from some finite initial voltage?

Comment: If you connect a capacitor to a conductor you will be exploring either an LC circuit, i.e. you will get oscillations, or you are looking at an antenna problem. I don't have a good suggestion on how to make this a well defined physics problem (but it sounds like there should be one), but I will be thinking about it.

Comment: Can't you just pick the L, R, and C values so that the behavior is overdamped and purely exponential?